# When I redirect the output of ls to a file, the filename is included in that file. How can I avoid this?

Tags: shell, command-line, io-redirection, ls

Observe:

```
$ ls
$ ls > list
$ cat list
list
```

This appears to indicate that when `ls` is executed that the redirection into file `list` has already begun and the `list` file is already created. A fine enough explanation at any rate, but the question is this: How can I prevent this from happening? What I expected to happen was `ls` would execute and its output dumped into `list` and that is what I want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you've noticed, the file is created before `ls` is run.  This is due to how the shell handles its order of operations.  In order to do

```
ls > file
```

the shell needs to *create* `file` and then set stdout to point to that and the finally run the `ls` program.

So you have some options.

1. Create the file in another directory (eg `/tmp`) and then `mv` it to the final directory
2. Create it as a hidden file (`.file`) and rename it
3. Use `grep` to remove the file from the output
4. Cheat :-)

The cheat would be something like

```
x=$(ls) ; printf "%s\n" "$x" > file
```

This causes the output of `ls` to be held in a variable, and then we write that out.

Comment: Nice. Your last paragraph prompted me to try `echo \`ls\` > ls` which I love for being so concise, but this doesnt put an entry on each line which my particular situation has issues with (as I very much do need to deal with directories with spaces in them today)...

Comment: `ls -1` will force single-column output

Comment: @StephenHarris Yeah I think i might as well give you the accept so somebody gets points, this answer is 99% of the way there. Do you think there are any race conditions or failure modes of `echo "$(ls -1)" > file`?

Comment: Yes, there are potential race conditions.  If you want to use this sort of cheat you really _should_ split the `ls` and the file creation into two steps.  Also beware of `echo` potentially interpreting the output of the `ls`; (what if you have a file called `-ne` ?).  That's why I used `printf` in my example.

Comment: Note that `x=$(ls)` removes all the trailing newline characters from the output of `ls` while your `printf '%s\n'` adds only **one** back.

Comment: @StevenLu: you could use echo with double quotes — ``echo "`ls`" > ls`` or `echo "$(ls)"`.

Comment: @StevenLu There are no race conditions, the order of evaluation is well-defined: the command substitution `$(ls)` is evaluated before the redirection `>file`. The reason you aren't getting one file per line is that you [didn't use double quotes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters): `echo "$(ls)" >file`

Answer (score 10):

The output file is created by the shell before `ls` begins. You can get around this by using `tee`:

```
ls | tee list
```

To thoroughly defeat any race condition, there is always

```
ls | grep -vx 'list' > list
```

Or if you like that `tee` displays the results as well:

```
ls | grep -vx 'list' | tee list
```

However, as pointed out in comments, things like this often break when filenames contain strange characters.  Unix filenames can generally contain any characters except for `NUL` and `/`, so parsing the output of `ls` is extremely difficult:

- Assigning to a shell variable can fail if a filename ends in one or more `\n`.
- Filtering with `grep` fails when the search term lies between `\n`.
- You can separate filenames with `NUL` instead of `\n` using `find`, but it can be difficult to convert this into something resembling the traditional sorted, newline-separated output of `ls`.
- Removing the output filename from the list may be incorrect if it already exists.

So the only truly effective way to do this is to create the output file somewhere else, and move it into place.  If you will never use `ls -a`, then this works:

```
ls > .list && mv .list list
```

If you might be using `ls -a`, then `.list` could appear in your output but no longer exist in the directory.  So then you would use a different directory, like `/tmp` to store the intermediate result.  Of course, if you always use `/tmp` you run into trouble there, so you can write a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
OUTDIR='/tmp'
if [ "${PWD}" = '/tmp' ]; then
  OUTDIR="${HOME}"
fi
ls > "${OUTDIR}/list" && mv "${OUTDIR}/list" list
```

This seems overly complicated for the task, though.

But the entire cause of the issue is that the shell is creating the output file before the command begins.  We can take that into consideration and just have the shell list the files for us.  Then we don't even need `ls` at all!

```
printf '%s\n' * > list
```

This will work until you have too many files in the directory to fit into an argument list.

Comment: Very neat! so here we are using the tee program to write to the file rather than leaving that task to the shell to do (which the shell ends up being overeager with for this particular situation)

Comment: I actually love that it shows the output on stdout... tee is really useful.

Comment: This fails to solve the problem if there are too many files in the directory.  There's an inherent race condition.  In an empty (or few files) directory it works, but with a lot of files the `tee` process can create the file before the `ls` has had a chance to read the whole directory.

Comment: I did it with 10,000 files and saw the race condition :-)  I was in the middle of writing it as an answer until I spotted it.  We can kludge with something nasty like `(sleep 1 ; tee file)`, but it's nasty.

Comment: Yup, `grep` is one of the options I listed as well.   Mostly I try to avoid this problem by using hidden files or other directories 'cos it's just nasty :-)

Comment: `grep -v '^list$'` or more simply: `grep -vx list` removes the line corresponding to the file called `list`, but also all those coming from filenames containing `<newline>list<newline>`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `moreutils` `sponge`:

```
ls | sponge list
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
cp =(ls) list
```

With GNU `ls`:

```
ls -I list > list
```

(though if there had been a file called `list` before, that means it won't be listed).

Since `ls` output is sorted anyway, you can also use (assuming your filenames don't contain newline characters):

```
ls | sort -o list
```

Or to avoid the double sorting, if your `ls` supports `-U` for `U`nsorted (beware some `ls` implementations have a `-U` for something else):

```
ls -U | sort -o list
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make the filename temporarily hidden:

```
ls >.list && mv .list list
```

Comment: OK i hadn't thought of this yet. It touches the filesystem a few times but it's somewhat intelligible, which is a big plus... Yes I'm looking for something concise and not too convoluted. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Partial/most credit goes to @StephenHarris...

```
echo "`ls`" > list
```

equivalent to

```
echo "$(ls)" > list
```

Comment: You don't need the `-1` option. It's implicit whenever `ls` isn't writing to a terminal (such as here, where it's writing to a pipe that the shell reads from).

Comment: @Gilles Right you are. I started trying it with `-1` in hopes it would fix it and it stuck around. I've edited the answer.