# why executing ls > empty.txt shows me empty.txt inside empty.txt in an empty folder?

Tags: process, io-redirection, output, input

why in an empty folder executing `ls > empty.txt` shows me **empty.txt** inside *empty.txt* ?

it is not poetry, it is true and I do not know why.

For me, they way to think `ls > empty.txt` is the following **step by step**:

1. `ls` is executed, and I get the output (**void** at that very moment)
2. `>` means I get the **output** of the previous command (actually `fd 2`)
3. `empty.txt` is the name of the file that gets the output of `ls` (nothing).

So why running

> cat empty.txt

I get

```
empty.txt
```

if the folder is empty?

Comment: Related: [When I redirect the output of ls to a file, the filename is included in that file. How can I avoid this?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296247/when-i-redirect-the-output-of-ls-to-a-file-the-filename-is-included-in-that-fil/296249)

Answer (score 5):

Your ordering is wrong. Rather than have every program know how to redirect the output, the shell does the redirection.

So what happens is

1. The shell starts a new shell to handle the command.
2. The original shell waits for the new shell to finish.
3. The new shell handles the `> empty.txt`, which involves creating the file.
4. The new shell replaces itself with `ls`
5. ls runs, listing the empty.txt file, and exits.
6. The original shell is notified that the new shell, which has become ls, has finished and prints a new prompt.